# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en MYSQL agrupadas de 3,4,5 actividades?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Buenas Tardes estoy sufriendo con una consulta que estoy implementando a mi sistema (en PHP con framework Laravel).

Tengo la siguiente consulta en MYSQL:

```
SET @item = 0;
select @item := @item + 1 as item,p.proyecto,ac.actividad,if(sum(a.valor) is null,0,sum(a.valor)) as valor_ganado,ac.valor as valor_planificado, if(sum(a.valor) is null,0,sum(a.valor))/ac.valor as spi from avance_tareas a inner join tareas t on a.idtarea=t.id right join actividades ac on t.idactividad=ac.id inner join proyectos p on ac.idproyecto=p.id where ac.idproyecto=1 group by ac.actividad order by item
```

y mi resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que mi resultado sea agrupados en 3, 4 y/o 5 actividades, mejor dicho quiero que mi resultado sea similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recalcar que la cantidad de agrupar lo realiza en el campo de Actividades.

Por favor cualquier ayuda será necesario.
Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No es claro el resultado buscado porque en la clumna actividad de la imagen hay varias filas con el mismo id de actividad

Comment: Lo que necesito hacer es agrupar mi consulta (1ra imagen) de 3, 4 o 5 actividades. Por ejemplo tomando como como referencia la primera imagen. Uniremos las 3 primeros actividades y mostraremos los demás campos (obviamente excepto los nombres) como valor_ganado, valor_planificado y spi pero promediado entre 3. Tal como se aprecia en la imagen 2, ahi ya estan agrupados por 3, 4 o 5 actividades.

Comment: Entonces, la columna actividades es la cantidad de registros agrupados! Ok, y cuál es el criterio para la agrupación que buscas?

Comment: Sin criterio, aunque tengo una duda podría agruparlo cada 3, 4 o 5 (así como la segunda imagen)?, de poderse me gustaria agrupar solamente de a 3.